# iMacros Not Recording With SalesForce

Tags: salesforce, imacros, salesforce-lightning

I'm desperate, so I'm reaching out here in case someone else has come across this issue.  I have used iMacros for a few years now as a way to close out mass quantities of support tickets within SalesForce. I have the free extensions for both Chrome and Firefox.  When SalesForce released the Lightning Experience, I realized a lot of my scripts didn't work any longer.  I admittedly don't know the back end of either SalesForce or iMacros, but it looks like the position numbers are labeled very differently in Lightning - to where the same type of page might require very different positions.  So as a result, I've always had to record and run my macros in SalesForce Classic.  It's an extra step to switch each time I'm doing this, but the mount of time I save when I'm actually running the macros greatly outweighs it...

So today, I needed to record a new macro, and I discovered it wasn't recording anything in Firefox.  I switched over to Chrome and saw the same thing.  I uninstalled and reinstalled the extension on both browsers and still no change.  I did switch over to Lightning, and try a few other web sites to see if I could record, and those all recorded without issue.  So I guess my question is twofold... Does anyone know why it's not recording in SalesForce Classic, or has anyone had similar experiences where recording in Lightning  has not worked due to the different positions within the macros - and if so, have you figured out how to get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All was resolved after I reboot my computer

Comment: Oh...!?, hum, Okay... That's a bit of a "strange" resolution, I would think, a bit surprising that iMacros for FF (v10.1.0 'Free') + CR (v10.1.1 'Free') was (still) working on different Sites in those 2 Browsers (both at around v113, I reckon), except for this 'Salesforce' Site both "Classic" + "Lightning" and it then works again (= can record) after a Reboot... But OK, glad it's working again for you, and Thanks for sharing.